# Force ClipRRect on BoxDecoration Image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I`m trying to make my image rounded, but as a background. Problem is, ClipRRect is not doing what i thought it was supposed to do. I would love solution other than using Stack because that way its gonna become a problem to size the image according to the column since the image is bigger than the column. Thank you very much.

Edit : So, i`m very sorry everyone. it seems that the image my colleague gave me was padded unintentionaly, hence the border doesnt work. Currently, me and my colleague already fixed the image and everything works fine now. I realized this by **using BoxFit.fill on the fit** so if someone might stumble upon this, they might want to try Boxfit.first to check the image.

[image]

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'images/ic_blackbackground.png',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 24,
                        bottom: 16,
                        left: 24,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Info Kios",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 1,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 24),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Nama Kios',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                widget._kurirPengambilanModel.pedagang.namaKios,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Nomor Kios',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                widget
                                    ._kurirPengambilanModel.pedagang.nomorKios,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your cliprect. `BorderRadius` of `DecoratedBox` is enough to achieve this.

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              'images/ic_blackbackground.png',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 24,
                bottom: 16,
                left: 24,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Info Kios",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 1,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 24),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Nama Kios',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget._kurirPengambilanModel.pedagang.namaKios,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Nomor Kios',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget._kurirPengambilanModel.pedagang.nomorKios,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```